# Update the plugin if it is already on the site

Tags: linux, wordpress, terminal, centos, updates

I have update plugin wordpress

And i want copy this update plugin folder to all website installed this plugin already before

like that:

```
if fastwpnow exist on /home/USERCLIENT/publich_html/wp-content/plugins/fastwpnow/ 

rm rf /home/USERCLIENT/publich_html/wp-content/plugins/fastwpnow/*

cp -R /home/MyUser/publich_html/wp-content/plugins/fastwpnow/* /home/USERCLIENT/publich_html/wp-content/plugins/fastwpnow/
```

How i can do that by linux terminal **[centos 7]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below bash script(tested on centos7)

or you can follow the same on terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function exec_main {

dir_name='/home/USERCLIENT/publich_html/wp-content/plugins/fastwpnow'
target_name='/home/MyUser/publich_html/wp-content/plugins/fastwpnow'

if [ -d $dir_name ] && [ -d $target_name ]
then

    rm -rvf $dir_name/*
    cp -Rv $target_name/* $dir_name

else
    echo "Error..."
fi

}

exec_main
```

1. save the above code as move_extensions.sh

then on terminal give permissions and execute:

```
chmod +x move_extensions.sh

./move_extensions.sh
```